# JQuery not recognizing that something happened in the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  $(".comment-form, .reply-form")
    .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
      debugger;
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .addClass('uneditable-input')
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
      debugger;
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .removeClass('uneditable-input')
        .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .val('');
      debugger;
      $(data.comments).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('fast')
```

This is supposed to run when something happens within the `.comment-form` and `.reply-form` divs. However, the code only runs when something happens in the `.comment-form`.

The `.comment-form` div shows up when the page loads, but the `.reply-form` div only appears when the "Reply" button is clicked. I think this may be the issue - that the `.reply-form` isn't there on the page load so when it actually does show up, JQuery doesn't recognize it's there. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: How is `.reply-form` loaded into the page?

Comment: Each comment has a link called "Reply". When "Reply" is clicked then a form is loaded into the page using AJAX with the div ".reply-form"

Comment: Just attach the listener once the element has been created.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you are inserting the form through the DOM. All you got to do is grab that object you created and add the handler then.

Comment: How do you add the handler? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Nvm I got it thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you handle listeners for dynamic elements (after ready event for example).

```js
//Use delegation
$('#delegationparent').on('click', 'div', function(){
  $('#results').html('Delegated div.');
  });
//Insert new div (didn't exist before)
$('<div>Delegate Div</div>').appendTo('#delegationparent');

//No delegate
//Create Div
var div = $('<div>No Delegate Div</div>');
//Attach handler to div
div.on('click', function(){
  $('#results').html('No delegated div');
  });
//Insert Div
div.appendTo('#nodelegate');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="delegationparent"></div>
<div id="nodelegate"></div>
<pre id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to add events to elements that are not present yet.

```
$('body').delegate('.comment-form, .reply-form', 'ajax:beforeSend', function (e, xhr, settings) {
  $(this).find('textarea')
    .addClass('uneditable-input')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: In the documentation, it says in jQuery 1.7+, .on() automatically uses delegation

Comment: It's basically the same thing though. `$(parentElement).on('ajax:success', '.comment-form, .reply-form', handler)`

Comment: Not sure if what I thought was the problem is actually the problem now. Because since .on() automatically does delegation, maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: I don't see how it would? If the element doesn't exist the jQuery object should return a collection of 0 items to attach the handler to, hence nothing happens.

Comment: Please post an example. Link only answers are bad form since the link can go stale.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on( events , selector , data )
```

Where event would be ajax:beforeSend and ajax:success
      selector would be .comment-form, .reply-form
      data would be (evt, xhr, settings) and (evt, data, status, xhr)

Will you please let me know if your code works if rewritten in the above format?

Didn't noticed that MinusFour has commented in the above post.

Comment: Thanks! This combined with MinusFour really helped.